# Apply changes to one string based on differences from another

Tags: php, function, string, diff

In PHP, I have two strings:

```
$str1 = 'amare';
```

... and ...

```
$str2 = 'laudare';
```

For $str2, there is an additional form which is ...

```
$form2 = 'laudant';
```

Now I would like to generate $form1 (for $str1) according to the change which was done from $str2 to $form2:

laudare -> laudant =====> amare -> amant

Can you help me to build a function which does that?

```
<?php
function generateForm($str1, $str2, $form2) {
    // 1) get the shared part of $str2 and $form2: "lauda"
    // 2) extract the according part for $str1: "ama"
    // 3) get the ending which has been suffixed: "nt"
    // 4) add the ending from step 3 to the base from step 2: "amant"
    // 5) return the string from step 4
}
?>
```

How can one implement this in PHP? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Surely you'd be better off trying to track down a genuine latin parser rather than cobbling together an over-simplistic rule that will only work in some cases anyway

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I have decided for a semi-automatic approach now, this is exactly what I need ;) But you're right: For automatic latin parsing, this would not be useful.

Comment: In that case, can't you simply check for a 1st conjugation infinitive "are" ending and replace with "ant"... or pass the conjugation through to the function rather than the infinitive of another 1st conjugation verb to be used as part of the manipulation

Comment: This would be possible as well, of course. But I want to offer the user an option list where he can choose how the word is inflected, e.g. "laudare is inflected like ... [amare, videre, regere]". The user then chooses an option and the word will be inflected according to the chosen word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function generateForm($str1, $str2, $form2) {
$p1=str_split($str2);
$p2=str_split($form2) ;
$i=0;
while($p1[$i]==$p2[$i])
{
  $i++ ;
}

$pre=strlen( substr($str2,$i));

$rep=substr($form2,$i);
return substr($str1,0,(strlen($str1)-$pre)).$rep;
}
```

this will work but not all the cases

Comment: Thank you very much, Muntasir! :) As your function works well and it is the faster solution (2.18 seconds against 3.09 seconds for 100,000 runs) your answer is the best one.

Comment: And I forget to mention: Your solution is extremely short - wonderful :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, but it only works if last letters are changed:

```
function generateForm($str1, $str2, $form2) {
    $commonStr = '';
    for($i = 0;$i < strlen($str2); $i++){
        if($str2{$i} == $form2{$i}){
            $commonStr .= $str2{$i};
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    $suffix1 = substr($str2, strlen($commonStr));
    $suffix2 = substr($form2,strlen($commonStr));

    $str1common = substr($str1, 0, strlen($str1)-strlen($suffix1));

    return $str1common . $suffix2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer :) It works well. But unfortunately, I had to choose one of the answers to be the best. And since Muntasir's solution is faster (2.18 seconds against 3.09 seconds for 100,000 runs) I chose his answer. But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function generateForm($str1, $str2, $form2) {
$str2Ar = preg_split('//', $str2, -1);
$form2Ar = preg_split('//', $form2, -1);
$match = '';
    foreach($str2Ar as $key=>$c)
    {
        if($c == $form2Ar[$key])
        $match .= $c;
        else
        break;
    }
    $pre = substr($str1,0,3);
    $sufix = substr($form2,strlen($form2)-2,2);
    $return_form = $match.$sufix;
    $return_according = $pre.$sufix;
    return array($return_form,$return_according);

}

$str1 = 'amare';
$str2 = 'laudare';
$form2 = 'laudant';

$result = generateForm($str1, $str2, $form2) ;
    echo $result[0];//return form
    echo "<hr>";
    echo $result[1];//return according
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and your fast reply, but this does not work for me. It gives wrong results.